# Zooming in at mouse position p5.js (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, geometry, zooming, p5.js

I'm trying to zoom at mouse position, like say on google maps. It kind of works but it shifts the point i want to zoom in on wherever it matches up with the original.Then when i zoom at that point it works fine. I think I need to translate the point back to the mouse, but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

This is the code before i draw:

```
  translate(zoomLocation.x, zoomLocation.y);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-zoomLocation.x, -zoomLocation.y);
  drawGrid();
```

And this is when I zoom:

```
  event.preventDefault();
  zoomLocation = {
    x: zoomLocation.x + (mouseX - zoomLocation.x) / zoom,
    y: zoomLocation.y + (mouseY - zoomLocation.y) / zoom
  };
  zoom -= zoomSensitivity * event.delta;
```

```js
let colors = {
  background: 0,
  gridLines: "white"
};

let nVariables = 4;

let zoom = 1;
let zoomLocation = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let zoomSensitivity = 0.0002;

function draw() {
  translate(zoomLocation.x, zoomLocation.y);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-zoomLocation.x, -zoomLocation.y);
  drawGrid();


  stroke("blue");
  ellipse(zoomLocation.x + (mouseX - zoomLocation.x) / zoom, zoomLocation.y + (mouseY - zoomLocation.y) / zoom, 10, 10);

  stroke("red");
  ellipse(zoomLocation.x, zoomLocation.y, 10, 10);

}

function setup() {
  zoomLocation = {
    x: 0,
    y: windowHeight / 2
  }
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function mouseWheel(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let oldZoom = zoom;
  zoomLocation = {
    x: zoomLocation.x + (mouseX - zoomLocation.x) / zoom,
    y: zoomLocation.y + (mouseY - zoomLocation.y) / zoom
  };
  zoom -= zoomSensitivity * event.delta;
}

function drawGrid() {
  let nCells = 2 ** nVariables;
  if (nCells > 2048) {
    if (!window.confirm(`You are about to create ${nCells} cells. This might lag your browser. Are you sure?`)) {
      return;
    }
  }
  background(colors.background);
  let gridWidth = windowWidth - 2;
  let gridHeight = min(gridWidth / nCells, windowHeight / 2 - 2);
  let gridY = windowHeight / 2;
  stroke(colors.gridLines);
  line(0, gridY, gridWidth, gridY);
  line(0, gridY + gridHeight, gridWidth, gridY + gridHeight);
  for (let i = 0; i < nCells + 1; i++) {
    line(i * (gridWidth / nCells), gridY, i * (gridWidth / nCells), gridY + gridHeight)
  }

  let curveHeight = 2;

  let drawVariable = (n) => {
    let p1 = {
      x: 1 / (2 ** (n + 1)) * gridWidth,
      y: gridY
    };
    let c1 = {
      x: p1.x,
      y: p1.y + gridWidth / (2 ** n) * curveHeight
    };
    let p2 = {
      y: p1.y
    };
    let c2 = {
      y: c1.y
    };;
    noFill();
    stroke("red");
    if (n == 0) {
      p2.x = gridWidth;
      c2.x = p2.x;
      c1.y = c2.y = p1.y + gridWidth / 2 * curveHeight;
      curve(c1.x, c1.y, p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, c2.x, c2.y);
      return;
    }
    for (let i = 3; i < 2 ** (n + 1); i += 2) {
      p2.x = i / (2 ** (n + 1)) * gridWidth
      c2.x = p2.x;
      if ((i - 3) % 4 == 0) {
        curve(c1.x, c1.y, p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, c2.x, c2.y);
      } else {
        p1.x = p2.x;
        c1.x = c2.x;
      }
    }
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < nVariables; i++) {
    drawVariable(i);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

button {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What is your desired effect?

Comment: The point under the mouse should remain at the same place on the screen, like zooming in google maps for example

Comment: this question should have more activity. I really needed this

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is an application of [Affine Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). Here's an example where I'm applying transformations incrementally to transform + scale at the mouse pointer location for a Google Maps type zoom effect: [Zoom Effect in p5.js Web Editor](https://editor.p5js.org/heothesennoc/sketches/JhGOH9VfC).

This is a good medium article that explains why this works: [Zooming at the Mouse Coordinates with Affine Transformations](https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/zooming-at-the-mouse-coordinates-with-affine-transformations-86e7312fd50b)

This is another good article that has some mathematical explanations on how it achieves the effects: [Affine Transformations — Pan, Zoom, Skew](https://farazzshaikh.medium.com/affine-transformations-pan-zoom-skew-96a3adf38eb2)